# bug in displaying data selected in listbox in text box

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, listbox

I am using the following code:

```
private void listBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    txtFrom.Clear();
    txtSubject.Clear();
    txtBody.Clear();
    something = this.listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();

    int something1 = Convert.ToInt32(something);

    foreach (MailMessage email in messages)
    {
        count++;
        if (count == something1)
        {
            txtFrom.Text = email.From.ToString();
            txtSubject.Text = email.Subject.ToString();
            txtBody.Text = email.Body.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when i select another item, the value of txtFrom.Text,txtSubject.Text, txtBody.Text, do not change according to the new value selected in the list box.

Answer (score 0):

The `MouseClick` event is not the one you want to handle if you're interested in learning when the selection changes. The `MouseClick` event is going to be raised every time that the user clicks inside of the control, regardless of whether they make a selection. And there are several ways to select an item inside of a listbox without even using the mouse—for example, I could change the selection using the arrow keys on the keyboard. (And if that's not enough to persuade you, I draw your attention to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.mouseclick.aspx), which says the `MouseClick` event "supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code".)

Instead, you'll want to switch to handling the [`SelectedIndexChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindexchanged.aspx) event. That event will be raised each time that the `SelectedIndex` property (or `SelectedIndices` collection for multi-select listboxes) changes, which happens automatically whenever a selection is made/changed.

You really don't even have to make any other changes to your code:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtFrom.Clear();
    txtSubject.Clear();
    txtBody.Clear();
    something = this.listBox1.SelectedIndex.ToString();

    int something1 = Convert.ToInt32(something);

    foreach (MailMessage email in messages)
    {
        count++;
        if (count == something1)
        {
            txtFrom.Text = email.From.ToString();
            txtSubject.Text = email.Subject.ToString();
            txtBody.Text = email.Body.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nothing happens when i run the code inside listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged, thus i had to use Mouse click event.

Comment: @iyerrama25 Then you have not wired up the event handler correctly. This event is raised each time the selection changes. That much is guaranteed by the documentation. In fact, the documentation I linked to even says: "This can be useful when you need to display information in other controls based on the current selection in the ListBox. You can use the event handler for this event to load the information in the other controls." Using `MouseClick` is not an option because it doesn't work. That much you've already learned. You need to figure out why `SelectedIndexChanged` isn't getting raised.

Comment: it could be because, there ain't any index to compare with for it to detect any change in the index i suppose

Comment: If there is currently nothing selected, then something gets selected, that still counts as a change. The value goes from nothing to something.